# In Visual Studio, how to solve Button image Quality?

Tags: image, visual-studio, button, customtaskpane

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to build an Excel Addin with a Custom Task Pane.

- In the User Control used as Custom Task Pane, i added `imlNavigation`(ImageList)
- I tried to generate transparent Images PNG with size [512,512] and attached it with the Buttons, but the Quality is very poor
- I tried to generate transparent Images PNG [16,16] but no changes.

Below is the screenshot. And even the transparency is not good. We still see those white colors around the pictures:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what exactly I shall do as I am still new in Visual Studio?

- Where could I get transparent Icons/Images to use for my Buttons?
- What Extension shall I use if necessary to get them easily attached with my Buttons?
- Where do I fail and I should still learn regarding the buttons?

I am willing to learn and to follow you instructions and suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be instead of using image list you can use **Image Resources**?

1. Click on the Button
2. On your property click on the assist button of `image`
3. From the **Select Resource** Dialog box, click on `Project Resource File`
4. Import you pictures (Png transparent) better 25-25px or 20-20px based on the size of your button. It accepts transparent images as well

This should improve the quality of your button images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZn3p.png)

Comment: Thank you so much @Andry, let me test it and will give my feedback to you. I almost forgot about this after waiting so long. Thanks your time!

Comment: Wow, this is powerful! I don't see anymore those white pixel with the transparent image. You are a blessing. Thank you soo much! You made my day!

Comment: I'm happy it saved you